# Why my django code is not sending Email to my newly register user?

Tags: python, django, smtp, sendmail, django-email

I want to verify new user registration by sending confirmation token to email of user. the code is showing no error in console but also not sending the email to user email. i am using django 3.0 and python 3.8.

the code is executing this part, when i signup a new user, this message poput but i am not receiving email `"Open your email to activate account."`

help me to fix this:

## views.py

```
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.views import View

from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_decode, urlsafe_base64_encode
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from .tokens import activation_token

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib import messages


class RegisterPageView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CreateUserForm()
        template_name = "register/register.html"
        return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            message_subject = "Activate your account"
            domain_url = get_current_site(request)
            user_email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            message = render_to_string(
                "Backend/accounts/activation_message.html",
                {
                    "domain": domain_url.domain,
                    "user": user,
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)),
                    "token": activation_token.make_token(user),
                },
            )
            email = EmailMessage(message_subject, message, to=[user_email])
            email.send()
            activation_msg = "Open your email to activate account."
            return render(
                request, "Backend/accounts/activate_email.html", {"activation_msg": activation_msg}
            )

        template_name = 'register/register.html'
        return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path("activate/<uidb64>/<token>", activate, name="activate"),
    path("register/", RegisterPageView.as_view(), name="register"),
]
```

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2","first_name","last_name")

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            user_email = User.objects.get(email=data)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exist")
```

## settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following could be one of the possibilities:

- Make sure that SMTP congifuration of your gmail account is alright and it allows access to django:
  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
- You can if it is not the problem of smtp by sending the email to console by changing EMAIL_BACKEND `'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'` To `"django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"`

  If email is displayed in console try account adapters settings: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
- Alternatively, you can try this code as it works for me:

```
     subject = 'Thank you for registering to our site'
          message = 'this is a test message'
          email_from = 'xyz@gmail.com'
          recipient_list = ['reciever@gmail.com', ]
          connection = [
              'xyz@gmail.com',
              'mypassword',
              False,
          ]
         send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, connection)
```

for this you will have to import send_mail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

Comment: i used send_mail method and it worked for me.thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. Kindly close this question by accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

Your email setting in setting.py should look like this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"  # mail service smtp
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "youremail@gmail.com"  # mymial is not any email: use environment variable to hide your email in production.
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "your email password"  # password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Note: You should make your gmail account less secure.

Go to this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/security)

And do as in figure.
[image]

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
class RegisterPageView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CreateUserForm()
        template_name = "register/register.html"
        return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            message_subject = "Activate your account"
            domain_url = get_current_site(request)
            user_email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            message = render_to_string(
                "Backend/accounts/activation_message.html",
                {
                    "domain": domain_url.domain,
                    "user": user,
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)),
                    "token": activation_token.make_token(user),
                },
            )
            user.email_user(subject, message) #try this
            activation_msg = "Open your email to activate account."
            return render(
                request, "Backend/accounts/activate_email.html", {"activation_msg": activation_msg}
            )

        template_name = 'register/register.html'
        return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})
```

Comment: Alternatively you can try user object method as `user.email_user(subject, message)` instead of **EmailMessage**

Answer (score 0):

I updated some part and rest are same..

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class RegisterPageView(View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = CreateUserForm()
            template_name = "register/register.html"
            return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                subject = "Activate your account"
                domain_url = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string(
                    "Backend/accounts/activation_message.html",
                    {
                        "domain": domain_url.domain,
                        "user": user,
                        "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                        "token": activation_token.make_token(user),
                    },
                )
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                send_mail(subject, message, 'mygmail@gmail.com', [to_email])
                activation_msg = "Open your email to activate account."
                return render(
                    request, "Backend/accounts/activate_email.html", {"activation_msg": activation_msg}
                )

            template_name = 'register/register.html'
            return render(request, template_name, {"form": form})

    def activate(request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None

        if user is not None and activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_active = True
            user.profile.email_confirmed = True
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request, "Backend/accounts/activation_fail.html")
```

i used `email_confirmed` to check email validtion,
 also i added `email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)` this line in my user profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField("Write Phone Name", max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField("Upload Client Image",null=True,blank=True)
    gender=models.CharField("Write gender", max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    position=models.CharField("Designation", max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

thats all.. thanks for your help